# Template argument deduction error in C++ variadic function

Tags: c++, functional-programming, variadic-templates

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace outcome {

    //// Class c_out (T)
    template <class T = void>
    class c_out {
        public:
            bool success = false;
            std::string error = "";
            T result;

            // Then
            template<typename Func, typename... Args>
            c_out<T> then(Func&& func, Args&&... args) const {
                if (success) {
                    return std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                } else {
                    return *this;
                };
            };

            // Error handler
            template<typename Func, typename... Args>
            c_out<T> except(Func&& func, Args&&... args) const {
                if (!success) {
                    return std::forward<Func>(func)(result, error, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                };
                return *this;
            };
    };

    //// Class c_out (void)
    template <>
    class c_out<void> {
        public:
            bool success = false;
            std::string error = "";

            // Then
            template<typename Func, typename... Args>
            c_out<void> then(Func&& func, Args&&... args) const {
                if (success) {
                    return std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                } else {
                    return *this;
                };
            };

            // Error handler
            template<typename Func, typename... Args>
            c_out<void> except(Func&& func, Args&&... args) const {
                if (!success) {
                    return std::forward<Func>(func)(error, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                };
                return *this;
            };
    };

    //// Run (void)
    template<typename Func, typename... Args>
    c_out<void> run(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
        return std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

    //// Failed
    template <class T>
    c_out<T> failed(T res, const std::string& error_msg) {
        c_out<T> outcome;
        outcome.success = false;
        outcome.error = error_msg;
        return outcome;
    };

    //// Failed (void)
    c_out<void> failed(const std::string& error_msg) {
        c_out<void> outcome;
        outcome.success = false;
        outcome.error = error_msg;
        return outcome;
    };
};

int main(void) {

    auto log_message = [](const std::string& msg) {
        std::cout<<msg<<std::endl;
        return outcome::c_out<>();
    };
    outcome::c_out<> out = outcome::run(log_message, "XXX").then(log_message, "YYY").except(outcome::failed);


    return 0;
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:92:108: error: no matching function for call to 'outcome::c_out<void>::except(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   92 |     outcome::c_out<> out = outcome::run(log_message, "XXX").then(log_message, "YYY").except(outcome::failed);
      |                                                                                                            ^
<source>:54:25: note: candidate: 'template<class Func, class ... Args> outcome::c_out<void> outcome::c_out<void>::except(Func&&, Args&& ...) const'
   54 |             c_out<void> except(Func&& func, Args&&... args) const {
      |                         ^~~~~~
<source>:54:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:92:108: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'Func'
   92 |     outcome::c_out<> out = outcome::run(log_message, "XXX").then(log_message, "YYY").except(outcome::failed);
  |
```

Why? How can I solve the template argument deduction error?

Comment: @KamilCuk How would you remove the normal *failed*?

Comment: One way: make `failed` a `tempalte <typename T> struct failed { c_out<T> operator() (...) {} };` and overload on void.

Comment: Btw, for me it looks strange, doesn't `outcome::run(log_message, "XXX").then(log_message, "YYY")` without the `except(..)` just return it already? `except(outcome::failed)` looks like it's meant to return a copy of the same as `then()` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`failed` is not a function, `failed` is an overload set.  You cannot name an overload set and pass it as an argument to a template and deduce a single function type.

```
[](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){return outcome::failed(decltype(args)(args)...);}
```

is a 95% compatible function object that dispatches to the overload set of `failed`.

There are many other ways to solve this as well.

Comment: How would you approach the run/then/except functions with overload sets? Is using the lambda the best option in your opinion?

Comment: @medical I'd drop Args... from most of your continuarion tyoe things.  They are passed through from outside function to outside function in boring ways and do little but make your code more complex.  Expect callers to use lambdas, but not boring boilerplate ones like I wrote.  Note that failed is a useless function (see comment on OP)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to the same you did with `c_out`:

```
//// Failed
template <class T = void>
struct failed {
    c_out<T> operator() (const std::string& error_msg, T res) {
        c_out<T> outcome;
        outcome.success = false;
        outcome.error = error_msg;
        return outcome;
    }
};

template <>
struct failed<void> {
    c_out<void> operator() (const std::string& error_msg) {
        c_out<void> outcome;
        outcome.success = false;
        outcome.error = error_msg;
        return outcome;
    }
};
```

but then a bit more ugly:

```
..........except(outcome::failed<>());
```